# how to make weasyprint show japanese characters instead of squares?

Tags: python, python-3.x, weasyprint

I'm trying to make weasyprint convert a html file into a pdf, but in the html file there are japanese characters, and instead of properly converting those, weasyprint converts it into squares with their utf code in it.

[Linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y12iu.png) is the image of what the pdf looks like. The empty squares between the lines of text have been added by me, so that's not part of the problem.

I've searched for the problem and found that others have encountered similar problems, but none of their solutions really worked. They all invovled installing a font to override the font weasyprint uses, but weasyprint just says that "[font] could not be loaded" when I try to do that.

I might've read the solutions wrong and screwed up a step in the fix, so if the font override method defintely works, I may need a more detailed guide on how to do it as I am not quite well versed in installing fonts and all that.

Comment: Take a look at the HTML file to find out which fonts it uses; they may be webfonts. Sounds to me like your conversion to PDF fails for Japanese glyphs because the font is not available, and therefore defaults to rendering squares. That’s to common fallback for glyphs that aren’t available, or for fonts that aren’t available.

Comment: How do I check the font my html file is using though?

Comment: Find some Japanese glyphs on the page, right-click on them to “Inspect” and then look at the font that the rendered HTML component uses.

Comment: Did you use `FontConfiguration` and a web font defined in the CSS?